# trying to install FOSUserBundle but getting error

Tags: php, symfony

trying to install **FOSUserBundle** bundle from below link [How to install 3rd party Bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/installation.html) but getting this error :

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]  
  The child node "db_driver" at path "fos_user" must be configured.
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You have forgotten to add the configuration for FOSUserBundle in your `app/config/config.yml` or at least did not provide a value for `fos_user.db_driver`.

You have to configure at least the db_driver , firewall and your user-class otherwise the configuration will throw an `InvalidConfigurationException`.

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Please see the documentation chapter [Step 5: Configure the FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-5-configure-the-fosuserbundle).

Comment: Step 5 needs to be done before step 1 because Step 1 fails.

Comment: I also had to add a config/packages/fos_user.yaml file [as seen here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2562#issuecomment-318862713)

Answer (score 1):

I solve similar error by updating composer : `/usr/local/bin/composer self-update`.
 May this help.