# Symfony FOSUser Bundle error The child node "db_driver" at path "fos_user" must be configured

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have just installed FOSUser bundle and initialized it in `AppKernel`'s `registereBundles()` function , when I run

```
console cache:clear
```

It get

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>   The child node "db_driver" at path "fos_user" must be configured.

My understanding was that unless or until I am not using a bundle it should not interfere in application flow. I wonder why I get this issue when I have done nothing with FOSUserBundle so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trying to install FOSUserBundle but getting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913809/trying-to-install-fosuserbundle-but-getting-error)

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel I am trying to understand the bundle flow not specifically the error which is generated , check the comment below. Its similar question but in different context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your config.yml you have to add primary data.

```
# FOSUser
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: UserBundle\Entity\User
```

It's configuration for ORM.

Comment: well I don't want to add that , its not that contradicts service-oriented-architecture ? Why its enforcing me to do it in first place. Forgive me I am not being rude , just understanding if a service should behave like this . I thought its only loaded when desired .

Comment: It need it because you registred bundle in AppKernel. When you do it, it create object, that after that initialize for example service.

Comment: you are right , docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html in step one says it right  `If you encounter installation errors pointing at a lack of configuration parameters, such as The child node "db_driver" at path "fos_user" must be configured, you should complete the configuration in Step 5 first and then re-run this step.`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your composer.json file by running 'composer update' in your terminal. I solved the similar error by updating it. May this help.

Answer (score 0):

Add Mail user and mail password

Make the following changes for getting rid of the error

## parameters.yml

parameters:
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null