# Symfony FOS user bundle initiation

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with installing FOS user bundle. I tried to search it everywhere, but probably I'm too dumb and can't find it.

I've created an entity called Admin and tried to run doctrine:schema:update --force
I've got an error: `The child node "from_email" at path "fos_user" must be configured.`

Here is my config.yml fos part.

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\Admin
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trying to install FOSUserBundle but getting error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913809/trying-to-install-fosuserbundle-but-getting-error)

Comment: Seen this question before and didn't find solution there :( I've tried to add node "from_email" with nodes "address" and "name" with values from fos docs but it still didn't work.

Comment: How did your config look like when you added them? What error did you get then?

Comment: The child node "from_email" at path "fos_user" must be configured.

Answer (score 51):

in your config.yml add `from_email` at path "fos_user":

```
# ...
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\Admin
    # ...
    from_email:
        address: you@example.com
        sender_name: You
# ...
```

More info : [Step 5: Configure the FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-5-configure-the-fosuserbundle)

Comment: Wow, thanks. I was using the recommended dev-master branch on fos and entered in panic mode when I saw the red line message...

Answer (score 1):

In your config.yml add from_email at path "fos_user":

```
fos_user:
  db_driver:      orm # can be orm or odm
  firewall_name:  main
  user_class:     Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser
  from_email:
    address: "%mailer_host%"
    sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```

and you get those values from **parameters.yml** file

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:

    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: "mailer_user"
```